# How to make width of ui-loader in jquery mobile loader wider?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Currently, I use Loader Widget from jQuery-mobile in my project. Here is the documentation: https://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/

The UI of the loading itself lies inside a div which has `ui-loader` class. In my case, I need to wider this element. I have tried to simply change its default width, but it instead broke up the element position. Therefore, is there any proper way to make the width of `ui-loader` wider?

Here is the code of mine:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/u1q4xjnt/1/

Here is the default condition:
[image]

After I tried to change its width, the position is not on the center page anymore:
[image]

Comment: Try to set `width: 100%` and `left: 0;`

Comment: @Krusader Nope, it doesn't work properly. :( https://ibb.co/ka3frR

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto;` here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/u1q4xjnt/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the positioning of the loader to absolute should work. Then it can be centered using the following CSS:

```
.ui-loader {
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
margin: 0;
}
```

This sets the position to absolute, and uses the combination of left, top and transform to center it. This should work no matter what the width is.

Hope this helps.